# Kentico BizForm API - how to create that form "anonymously" from the backend with logged-in user?

Tags: c#, api, kentico

We have an existing Kentico-driven site. On top of that site, we created a user-friendly app to allow managers to enter data into Kentico database. Essentially we are using Kentico API from our backend code to creating a `BizForm` object in Kentico. The problem I'm facing is that when managers enter information on our site, everything is done in the context of MANAGER - and therefore Kentico updates manager's contact information with CUSTOMER information they just entered.

Here is what happens:

1. Manager John has USER account in Kentico.
2. He logs in into our app. We call AuthenticationHelper.AuthenticateUser() for him, and set a cookie. Every API is protected with `[Autorize]` attribute
3. Then he fills in information for Susie (a customer) and we call `BizFormInfoProvider.GetBizFormInfo().Insert()` to create new form object in Kentico.
4. Form is created - but ***John's contact info*** (in `OM_Contact` table) in Kentico is **updated** and becomes Susie's info.

I guess I either need to tell Kentico to create BizForm anonymously (and it will match email on the form to a contact, if exists), or I need to tell Kentico to disable automatic "matching" of form and contact - but I was not able to figure out how to do that. Or may be there is another way?

we have Kentico 11 and use it with .net API

Answer (score 2):

It must be a Contact Mapping configured for form ([refer to Kentico docs](https://docs.kentico.com/k11/on-line-marketing-features/configuring-and-customizing-your-on-line-marketing-features/configuring-contacts/mapping-fields-to-contact-attributes#Mappingfieldstocontactattributes-Mappingon-lineformfields)). To disable this behavior, you just need to remove this mapping from Form configuration. Or it might be enough just to untick "Override" checkbox.